# How to decode Javascript Unicode into C# strings

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, security, encoding

For example the JSON callback we get on a google autosearch:

```
window.google.td && window.google.td('tljp1322487273527014', 4,{e:"HY7TTtmRFZPe8QPCvf30Dw",c:1,u:"http://www.google.co.uk/s?hl\x3den\x26cp\x3d5\x26gs_id\x3d17\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dowasp\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy-ab\x26source\x3dhp\x26pbx\x3d1\x26oq\x3d\x26aq\x3d\x26aqi\x3d\x26aql\x3d\x26gs_sm\x3d\x26gs_upl\x3d\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb\x26fp\x3dbd20912ccdf288ab\x26biw\x3d387\x26bih\x3d362\x26tch\x3d4\x26ech\x3d15\x26psi\x3d5o3TTqCqCsnD0QXA7sUI.1322487273527.1\x26wrapid\x3dtljp1322487273527014",d:"[\x22owasp\x22,[[\x22owasp\x22,0,\x220\x22],[\x22owasp\\u003Cb\\u003E top 10\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x221\x22],[\x22owasp\\u003Cb\\u003E top 10 2011\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x222\x22],[\x22owasp\\u003Cb\\u003E zap\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x223\x22]],{\x22j\x22:\x2217\x22}]"});window.google.td && window.google.td('tljp1322487273527014', 4,{e:"HY7TTtmRFZPe8QPCvf30Dw",c:0,u:"http://www.google.co.uk/s?hl\x3den\x26cp\x3d5\x26gs_id\x3d17\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dowasp\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy-ab\x26source\x3dhp\x26pbx\x3d1\x26oq\x3d\x26aq\x3d\x26aqi\x3d\x26aql\x3d\x26gs_sm\x3d\x26gs_upl\x3d\x26bav\x3don.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb\x26fp\x3dbd20912ccdf288ab\x26biw\x3d387\x26bih\x3d362\x26tch\x3d4\x26ech\x3d15\x26psi\x3d5o3TTqCqCsnD0QXA7sUI.1322487273527.1\x26wrapid\x3dtljp1322487273527014",d:""});
```

more specifically, how to go from:

```
"\x22te\\u003Cb\\u003Esco\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x220\x22"
```

to

```
"te\u003Cb\u003Esco\u003C\/b\u003E",0,"0"
```

to

```
"te<b>sco</b>"
```

Note that the System.Web UrlDecode and HtmlDecode are not able to handle this.

Interestingly, the AntiXss almost does the reverse, since it can go from:

```
"te<b>sco</b>"
```

To

```
te\00003Cb\00003Esco\00003C\00002Fb\00003E
```

**Security angle**

These decodings have a number of security implications since they will be rendered by the browser. For example if in Javascript/jQuery we have a variable with the payload

```
var xss = "te\u003Cscript\u003Ealert\u002812\u0029\u003C\u002Fscript\u003E"
```

will be triggered if assigned to a div's html

```
$("#header").html(xss)
```

Comment: Are we talking about C# or JavaScript here?

Answer (score 4):

```
\x....
```

WTF? \u - dat's okey.
According to previous answer:

```
string str = @"P\u003e\u003cp\u003e Notes \u003cstrong\u003e Разработчик: \u003c/STRONG\u003e \u003cbr /\u003eЕсли игра Безразлично";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\\u([0-9a-z]{4})",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
str = regex.Replace(str, match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `"\x22te\\u003Cb\\u003Esco\\u003C\\/b\\u003E\x22,0,\x220\x22"` is hex encoded, there is nothing available to decode this string out of the box, however the following should work:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})");
var replaced = regex.Replace(input, match => char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)));
```